# Excel VBA macro Script : Find value from Sheet 1 in Sheet 2 and Copy Value found

Tags: vba, excel

I am facing the following challenge : I have an Excel Sheet with values on column A (ex. ,, C Klasse,A Klasse,Golf,Astra" ).

On the Second Sheet I have 2 columns A &  B containing the following Information : Column A ,,Mercedes,Opel,VW etc." and on B column I have the following ,,C Klasse,A Klasse,Golf,Astra" (the same information as on Sheet 1 column A).

**Goal** : Find the value from Sheet 1 ,Column A in Sheet 2 Column B -> copy value from Sheet 2 column A -> Paste into Sheet 1 column M.

**Example** : A2 = C Klasse -> Find ,,C Klasse'' in Sheet 2 - > Found ,,C Klasse'' in B42 -> Copy Content from  A42 ,,Mercedes'' - > Paste M2.

This is the code that I came up with ,I just started this so please bear with me :

```
Range("A2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Form2").Select
Cells.Find(What:=Range("A2"), After:=ActiveCell, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Range("A193").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Position:=xlFirst
Sheets("Form1").Select
Range("M2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

[image]

Comment: See [Section 4 – Making .Find work as Vlookup formula](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Comment: Hey @Siddarth Rout, my request is more complex than Section 4 (although a good read for a newbie like myself) in your example you have data like : B5 = J5 .  This is not the case for me.My Data is more like B5 = A22 (from a different Sheet).

Comment: So you need to set the range accordingly :) The same principle applies... Imagine that the data is in another sheet and in Col A...

Comment: This is the only part that I edited:
    'Set ws = Worksheets("Form1")
    Set UpdateRange = ws.Range("A2:A30")
    Set ws = Worksheets("Form2")
    Set DataRange = ws.Range("B1:B500")'

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of how your data look?

Comment: @SiddharthRout this it how it looks like : http://1.2.3.10/bmi/i.imgur.com/6Za4ImY.png

Comment: try this : http://imgur.com/6Za4ImY

Comment: Yeah... so I was right... My code can easily help you. Though you don't need VBA for this.

Comment: What do you mean? How could I solve this without VBA?

Comment: You want to put the brands in col B right after matching with sheet2 data. So `B2:B8` will be `VW` and so on?

Comment: yes ,right. But this is only a part of the macro.Before that I have a lot of data being copy pasted,in different sheets.And I cannot say that after the the macro is running,what Model I'm going to have in A5 or A247 for example.I have about 10 Sheets, all starting with Model and on each sheet I have to add the Brand

Comment: That is not a problem. But you are ok with formulas right?

Comment: I think I know what you are referring to ,but I don't know how to put it in to Practice :)

Comment: If you reverse the columns in Sheet2 then it is a straight `Vlookup` formula.

Comment: yep! you are right Vlookup is solving my Problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want you can post it as an answer :)

Comment: I will do so,but it's your answer :) . Just one last question is there any way to configure the copy paste option? For example I have the formula =VLOOKUP(A2,Ressort!A1:B232,2,FALSE) ; If I Drag the formula to the other Rows ,the formula changes to =VLOOKUP(A3,Ressort!A3:B233,2,FALSE) . Is there a way to change only the first value when dragging the formula?

Comment: Change `=VLOOKUP(A2,Ressort!A1:B232,2,FALSE)` to `=VLOOKUP(A2,Ressort!$A$1:$B$232,2,FALSE)` Notice the `$` signs ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this Problem was solved by using Excel Formula VLOOKUP not VBA.

The formula looks like this : =VLOOKUP(A2,Ressort!$A$1:$B$232,2,FALSE)

Many thanks to @Siddharth Rout - he is the one who opened my eyes! :)

Comment: + 1 For solving it yourself :)

Comment: For new users,  Ressort above is the name of the second sheet, not a sorting command. Better for beginners to use SheetA, SheetB, etc. in examples.